# Multiple inserts into SQLite getting data from other tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

In SQLite, I have a simple message board where I want to timestamp when each user first sees any post.

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    message_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    mb_topic_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES mb_topics(mb_topic_id),
    message_poster INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    message_content TEXT,
    message_post_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now'))
)

CREATE TABLE messages_seen (
    message_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES messages(message_id),
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    seen_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now')),
    UNIQUE (message_id, user_id)
)
```

What I want to do, in one SQL statement if possible is when a user loads a message thread, to `INSERT OR IGNORE` into `messages_seen` their `userID` (which I have) for each `message_id` matching the `mb_topic_id` (which I have).

So if the user_id is 4 and the mb_topic_id is 7, I could do something like:

```
SELECT message_id FROM messages WHERE mb_topic_id = 7
```

And that could return something like (9,11,14,26).  And from that I'd do:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO messages_seen (message_id, user_id) VALUES (9,4);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO messages_seen (message_id, user_id) VALUES (11,4);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO messages_seen (message_id, user_id) VALUES (14,4);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO messages_seen (message_id, user_id) VALUES (26,4);
```

Is there a way to squeeze that into one statement?  BTW, the server that I'm running this on is running SQLite 3.6.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT: Irrelevant suggestion about SQLite 3.7.11 removed]

You could use insert-select with the user id as a literal:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO messages_seen (message_id, user_id) 
SELECT message_id, 4
FROM   messages 
WHERE  mb_topic_id = 7
```

Comment: I did see the thing about 3.7... which is why I specified that the server I'm using is running 3.6.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I missed that in the OP for some obscure reason. I'll remove that from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports using [`SELECT` statements in `INSERT` statements](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

For example:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO messages_seen (message_id, user_id)
SELECT message_id, user_id
FROM ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the statement there... selecting user_id from messages?  There is no user_id in messages.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed - My apologies.  I meant it merely as an example.  You'll simply use whatever query returns the records you intend to insert.